# basic linear algebra question, angles between vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u = (x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $(x',y',0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be such that $x \geq y \geq 0$ and $x' \geq y' \geq 0$. Can we show that the angle between $u$ and $v$ is at most $\pi/4$?

I believe this is the case since both $u$ and $v$ will live in the triangle spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and $(1,1,0)$, which have an angle of $\pi/4$ between them, but a proof (or counterexample!) would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The angle $\theta$ between two vectors $v$ and $w$ is
$$
\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{v\cdot w}{\|v\|\cdot\|w\|}\right)
$$

Comment: I don't quite see how this answers my question... We can assume wlog that $||v|| = ||w|| = 1$, but still, showing $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$ reduces to $1/\sqrt{2} \leq \cos(\theta) \leq 1$ ... but even if we showed that we would have the possibility of $3\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$... and even then, how could we show $1/\sqrt{2} \leq cos(\theta)$?

Comment: Actually we can't have $3\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ since both vectors are in the first octant, but the other question of why $1/\sqrt{2} \leq \cos(\theta) \leq 1$ still remains.